# How to split a word in all possible combinations based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a fake language generator that anyone can input the values like this for example

```
d = f
e = k
o = u
n = j
m = p
de = ed
mo = om
```

So the way it should work, for example the word

> *demon*

can output:

> - fkomj ( *D* | *E* | *M* | *O* | *N* )
> - edomj ( *DE* | *MO* | *N* )
> - edpuj ( *DE* | *M* | *O* | *N* )
> - fkpuj ( *D* | *E* | *MO* | *N* )

based on the array i supplied, so basically for i need the word split in each combination possible based on my input array

I've tried working with an loop in the word and splitting it in offsets and sizes but didnt gave the result i wanted because it was giving parts that i didnt had in the array

Comment: nice idea, what have you tried?

Comment: I would start by using a map to define characters and their counter parts. Then you would want to parse the string for all mapped characters. a mapped character can be a single char or a string.

Comment: So for now, i tried splitting it based on characters, for example, i gave it an offset and size and it returned me the word like
`DE|MO|N - With Offset = 0 and size = 2
D|E|M|O|N - With Offset = 0 and size = 1
D|EM|ON - Width Offset = 1 and size = 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate an object with all indices of the found pattern and then collect the parts and map new strings.

```js
function getParts(string, parts) {

    function collectParts(index, parts) {
        if (index === string.length) {
            result.push(parts);
            return;
        }
        if (!indices[index]) return;
        indices[index].forEach(s => collectParts(index + s.length, [...parts, s]));
    }

    var indices = {},
        result = [];

    Object.keys(parts).forEach(function (k) {
        var p = string.indexOf(k);
        while (p !== -1) {
            (indices[p] = indices[p] || []).push(k);
            p = string.indexOf(k, p + 1);
        }
    });

    collectParts(0, []);

    return result.map(a => a.map(k => parts[k]).join(''));
}

console.log(getParts('demon', { d: 'f', e: 'k', o: 'u', n: 'j', m: 'p', de: 'ed', mo: 'om' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A shorter approach by using substrings of the given string and using a short circuit to exit longer parts.

```js
function getParts(string, pattern) {

    function collectParts(left, right) {
        if (!left) return result.push(right);
        sizes.some(s => {
            if (left.length < s) return true;
            var key = left.slice(0, s);
            if (key in pattern) collectParts(left.slice(s), right + pattern[key]);
        });
    }

    var sizes = [...new Set(Object.keys(pattern).map(k => k.length))].sort((a, b) => a - b),
        result = [];

    collectParts(string, '');
    return result;
}

console.log(getParts('demon', { d: 'f', e: 'k', o: 'u', n: 'j', m: 'p', de: 'ed', mo: 'om' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, never would thought in that way, thanks once more :)